# Count values in a column in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a city-name column and I want to count the number duplicates for each city. Is there a way I can generate the output without having to enter the labels in the output (like this one https://exceljet.net/formula/summary-count-with-countif)?

Input: 

`Thai Binh
Dong Thap
Ha Noi
Ha Noi
Daklak
Ha Noi
Hai Duong
Thai Binh`

Output

`Thai Binh----2
Dong Thap----1
Ha Noi-------3
Daklak-------1
Hai Duong----1`

Comment: Pivot tables might be a fast way to get this result.  You could even copy and paste as values the result from that calculation if you wanted.

Comment: Following answer solved your problem? Or still need you help?

Answer (score 0):

If your table is like this:

```
 |   A     |
1|Thai Binh| 
2|Dong Thap|
3|Ha Noi   |
4|Ha Noi   |
5|Daklak   |
6|Ha Noi   |
7|Hai Duong| 
8|Thai Binh|
```

Use this formula to extract unique values:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$8, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($E$1:E1, $A$1:$A$8), 0)),"")
```

Put it into cell `E2` then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Then use `COUNTIF()` formula to count an occurrence:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$8,E2)
```

Put it into cell `F2` then fill down.

[image: 1]